# Sum of elements of a recursive sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

Say we have $$a_n=\frac{n-1+b}{n-b}a_{n-1}$$ with $a_0>0$ and $-1<b<0$. Then it holds that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=-\frac12 a_0.$$ 
I could establish this using simple manupulations with $\Gamma$ and $Beta$ funtions. I was however wondering if one could do it differently. I appreciate if you share your fun on this problem with me :-)

Comment: Attempting a purely algebraic approach I got to the basic $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{k+b-1}{k-b}$$ but I'm struggling to find a way to simply this using basic methods... perhaps taking some time off the problem will allow me new insight looking back tomorrow.

Comment: This notation can be simplified to $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{b^{(k)}}{(1-b)^{(k)}}$$ using the rising factorial function if I haven't made any errors yet in transcribing my math (very unlikely XD), and perhaps some simple properties of the rising factorial function could help here...

Answer (score 4):

The result depends
on two different ways
of writing the recurrence.

The first way is
$a_n
=(1-\frac{1-2b}{n-b})a_{n-1}
$.
From this
we show that
$a_m
<a_0m^{-(1-2b)}
$
or
$ma_m
<a_0m^{-2b}
$.

The second way is
$na_n-(n-1)a_{n-1}
=b(a_n+a_{n-1})
$.
Summing this,
we get
$\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}a_{n}
=\frac{(m-b)a_m}{2b}-\frac{a_0}{2}
$.

Letting $m \to \infty$,
since
$ma_m \to 0$
as $m \to \infty$
(from the first result,
since $b < 0$),
we get the desired result.

Now, the details.

$\begin{array}\\
a_n
&=\frac{n-1+b}{n-b}a_{n-1}\\
&=\frac{n-b-1+2b}{n-b}a_{n-1}\\
&=(1+\frac{2b-1}{n-b})a_{n-1}\\
&=(1-\frac{1-2b}{n-b})a_{n-1}\\
\text{so}\\
\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}
&=1-\frac{1-2b}{n-b}\\
\text{or}\\
\ln(a_n)-\ln(a_{n-1})
&=\ln(1-\frac{1-2b}{n-b})\\
&\lt -\frac{1-2b}{n-b}
\qquad\text{since }
\ln(1-x) < -x.\\
\text{Summing,}\\
\ln(a_m)-\ln(a_0)
&\lt -\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{1-2b}{n-b}\\
&<-(1-2b)\ln(m)\\
\text{or}\\
a_m
&<a_0m^{-(1-2b)}\\
\end{array}
$.

We have
$(n-b)a_n
=(n-1+b)a_{n-1}
$
or
$na_n-(n-1)a_{n-1}
=b(a_n+a_{n-1})
$.

Summing,

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=1}^m(na_n-(n-1)a_{n-1})
&=\sum_{n=1}^m(b(a_n+a_{n-1}))\\
&=b\sum_{n=1}^ma_{n-1}+b\sum_{n=1}^ma_{n}\\
&=b\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}a_{n}+b\sum_{n=1}^ma_{n}\\
&=b(a_0+a_m+2\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}a_{n})\\
\text{or}\\
ma_m
&=b(a_0+a_m+2\sum_{n=1}^{m}a_{n})\\
\text{or}\\
\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}a_{n}
&=\frac{ma_m}{2b}-\frac{a_m}{2}-\frac{a_0}{2}\\
&=\frac{(m-b)a_m}{2b}-\frac{a_0}{2}\\
\end{array}
$

We have shown that
$ma_m
<a_0m^{2b}
\to 0
$
since $b < 0$.

Therefore,
letting $m \to \infty$,
we are done!!!!

Comment: A very interesting approach! Briefly looking at this for a minute or two I found it a little hard to follow...  I'll have to take a longer look later. The proof looks pretty beautiful though!  That inequality you derived at the beginning seemed almost useless to me,  but you brought it all around in the end.  I'll have to use this proof outline sometime!

Comment: Brevan: I did a rewrite and reformat. Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: this proof is definitely more linear now,  and thus easier to understand!!

Comment: One thing I really about this proof is how elementary it is. The only thing beyond algebra is the part using $\ln$.

Comment: Absolutely.  While the logic is a little more involved than my proof (possibly even with the partial sums),  the proof remains conceptually simple.

Comment: that looks quite interesting! +1 many thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

I solved this using the Rising Factorial function (with partial sums using the Gamma function, although I hope to remove this by finding a simpler proof of my last step)
$$\begin{align}a_n & = \frac{n+b-1}{n-b}a_{n-1}\\
&=\frac{n+b-1}{n-b}\frac{n+b-2}{n-b-1}a_{n-2}\\
&=\frac{b+n-1}{n-b}\frac{b+n-2}{n-1-b}\cdots\frac{b}{1-b}a_0\\
&=a_0\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k+b-1}{k-b}\end{align}$$
$$\implies \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n = a_0\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{k+b-1}{k-b}$$
$$=a_0\left(\frac{b}{1-b}+\frac{(b)(b+1)}{(1-b)(2-b)}+\frac{(b)(b+1)(b+2)}{(1-b)(2-b)(3-b)}+\cdots\right)$$
$$=\frac{b^{(1)}}{(1-b)^{(1)}}+\frac{b^{(2)}}{(1-b)^{(2)}}+\frac{b^{(3)}}{(1-b)^{(3)}}+\cdots$$
$$=a_0\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{b^{(k)}}{(1-b)^{(k)}}\right)$$
$$=\color{red}{-\frac{1}{2}a_0}$$
The last part can be done by converting to a gamma representation and using partial sums, although I feel there must be an easier way... doing so is most easily done using Mathematica (as I did), but I am sure there is a more elementary proof out there. I will continue the search. I still feel that sharing most of a proof is better than nothing, so I provide this answer anyway.

Comment: I made my answer clearer (I hope).

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. :-) +1